# Как протестировать скорость чтения/записи блочного устройства

Tags: linux, shell

Всё что до сих пор видел по этой теме - `hdparm -tT` и `dd` с кучей не совсем понятных параметров.

Что хотелось бы видеть: зависимость скоростей чтения и записи от размера блока и его позиции. Разумеется программа должна работать из командной строки без графической среды.

Comment: Что именно вы просите: а) написать за вас программу или б) посоветовать уже существующую программу?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что не соответствует тематике ruSO - тут не пишут программы за людей.

Comment: http://www.slashroot.in/linux-file-system-read-write-performance-test

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/154235/ тут здоровенная простынь как раз про винт\винты и их скорость.

Comment: @Roman а выбирайте сами а или б

Comment: @Denis этот сайт для коллекции знаний, думаю ответы на этот вопрос помогут в решении этой конкретной задачи программирования и администрирования. Написание программ как раз не запрещено на этом сайте, я не просил вас об этом, но буду рад если кто напишет хорошую программу или её фрагмент.

Answer (score 6):

[iops](https://github.com/cxcv/iops) - как раз то, что вы просите. Выдает таблицу БЛОК | СКОРОСТЬ

```
/dev/md0,  12.00 TB, 32 threads:
 512   B blocks:  466.5 IO/s, 233.3 KiB/s (  1.9 Mbit/s)
   1 KiB blocks:  453.2 IO/s, 453.2 KiB/s (  3.7 Mbit/s)
   2 KiB blocks:  445.0 IO/s, 890.1 KiB/s (  7.3 Mbit/s)
   4 KiB blocks:  465.0 IO/s,   1.8 MiB/s ( 15.2 Mbit/s)
   8 KiB blocks:  441.4 IO/s,   3.4 MiB/s ( 28.9 Mbit/s)
  16 KiB blocks:  444.9 IO/s,   7.0 MiB/s ( 58.3 Mbit/s)
  32 KiB blocks:  433.9 IO/s,  13.6 MiB/s (113.7 Mbit/s)
  64 KiB blocks:  444.8 IO/s,  27.8 MiB/s (233.2 Mbit/s)
 128 KiB blocks:  465.3 IO/s,  58.2 MiB/s (487.9 Mbit/s)
 256 KiB blocks:  409.0 IO/s, 102.3 MiB/s (857.8 Mbit/s)
 512 KiB blocks:  212.4 IO/s, 106.2 MiB/s (890.8 Mbit/s)
   1 MiB blocks:  142.3 IO/s, 142.3 MiB/s (  1.2 Gbit/s)
   2 MiB blocks:   67.1 IO/s, 134.2 MiB/s (  1.1 Gbit/s)
   4 MiB blocks:   40.9 IO/s, 163.7 MiB/s (  1.4 Gbit/s)
   8 MiB blocks:   21.5 IO/s, 171.6 MiB/s (  1.4 Gbit/s)
```

Comment: наверно то, что нужно, но где её найти?

Comment: @sercxjo а какой у вас дистрибутив?

Comment: ubuntu vivid 15.04

Comment: @sercxjo тривиальный вариант apt-get install iops вы попробовали?

Comment: Конечно пробовал. И в packages.ubuntu.com данного файла не нашёл ни в одном пакете

Comment: https://github.com/cxcv/iops похоже это она?

Comment: @sercxjo, да, это она

Comment: Правда, не умеет ни писать, ни работать с заданной частью (это в соответствии с `зависимость скоростей чтения и записи от размера блока и его позиции` в вопросе) девайса.

Comment: @avp И к тому же выдаёт ошибку "Invalid argiment" на 32-битном linux 3.19, но это я поправил

Comment: @sercxjo, тогда, наверное, сможете и добавить пару аргументов, задающих диапазон блоков для тестирования. Остается извлечь откуда-то (из информации форматирования?, а если мы в lvm?, а если устройство отображено на SAN? (я вижу тут много варианов и проблем с универсальностью)) мапирование данного блочного устройства на реальный девайс.

Comment: @avp я вижу тут слово из трех букв - "КЭШ" причем где-нибудь внутри SAN, который не отключить, не обойти, не задетектить.

Comment: O_DIRECT сначала был, сейчас вырезан, короче кэш тут ещё и просто системный, поэтому перед запуском надо его сбросить

Answer (score 6):

**Команда `dd`** позволяет замерить скорость последовательного чтения/записи.

Для чтения более достоверный результат даёт прямое чтение без участия системного кэша в режиме `iflag=direct`:

```
# dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/null bs=16M count=8 iflag=direct
8+0 записей получено
8+0 записей отправлено
скопировано 134217728 байт (134 MB), 6,17806 c, 21,7 MB/c
```

Для точности измерений при записи важно дождаться её окончания а не помещения вывода в кэш. Лучший результат даёт режим `conv=fdatasync`. Режим `oflag=direct` обычно даёт результат хуже и он дальше от возможного реального использования. **ВНИМАНИЕ! Нижеприведённая команда приведёт к потере данных на устройстве /dev/sdb**

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=16M count=8 conv=fdatasync
8+0 записей получено
8+0 записей отправлено
скопировано 134217728 байт (134 MB), 11,7765 c, 11,4 MB/c
```

Некоторые диски могут работать медленнее со случайными данными чем с нулями. Использовать `/dev/urandom` и тем более `/dev/random` напрямую вместо `/dev/zero` нельзя, так как они требуют много вычислений и тормозят процесс. Поэтому нужно сначала подготовить файл с данными (лучше на tmpfs).

```
# dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/shm/random bs=16M count=8
8+0 записей получено
8+0 записей отправлено
скопировано 134217728 байт (134 MB), 15,2181 c, 8,8 MB/c
```

Как видите, если бы мы напрямую копировали /dev/urandom в /dev/sdb, мы бы получили скорость вычислений псевдослучайных чисел, а не скорость записи. Теперь проверяем с заготовленными данными.
**ВНИМАНИЕ! Нижеприведённая команда приведёт к потере данных на устройстве /dev/sdb**

```
# dd if=/dev/shm/random of=/dev/sdb bs=16M count=8 conv=fdatasync
8+0 записей получено
8+0 записей отправлено
скопировано 134217728 байт (134 MB), 11,7722 c, 11,4 MB/c
# rm /dev/shm/random
```

Получил тот же результат. Значит скорость моего устройства не зависит от данных.

**Команда `fio`** делает много разных вариантов тестов, но результаты выводятся в не очень удобном формате, хотя там очень много разных подробностей.
Для получения зависимости скорости от размера блока написал следующий скрипт (`diskspeed.sh`), надеюсь он будет полезен:

```
#!/bin/bash
bs="512 1024 2048 4096 8192 16384 32768 65536 131072 262144 524288 1048576 2097152 4194304"
testtype=randread
iodepth=100
iolimit=40M
timelimit=5
test=true
for i in "$@" ; do
  case $i in
    bs=*|testtype=*|iodepth=*|iolimit=*|timelimit=*|dev=*) eval "$i" ;;
    notest|test=no|test=false) test=false
  esac
done

if [ -z "$dev" ] ; then
    echo "Usage: $0 dev=/dev/sd... [{bs,testtype,iodepth,iolimit,timelimit,test}=<value>...]"
    exit 0
fi
[ -z "$dir" ] && dir="${dev##*/}-$testtype"
mkdir -p "$dir"
cd $dir

$test && for i in $bs ; do
fio --output=$i - <<EOF
[readtest$i]
filename=$dev
rw=$testtype
direct=1
buffered=0
ioengine=libaio
iodepth=$iodepth
blocksize=$i
io_limit=$iolimit
runtime=$timelimit
EOF
echo -ne '\r\e[K\r' >&2
done

egrep '^ *(READ|WRITE) *:' $bs | sort -n | sed -r 's/([0-9]+):.*aggrb=([0-9]+).*/\1 \2/'
```

Примеры запуска скрипта с sd-картой

Случайное чтение

```
# ./diskspeed.sh dev=/dev/sdb
512 187
1024 432
2048 937
4096 1706
8192 3281
16384 5901
32768 8128
65536 9239
131072 10149
262144 11445
524288 11606
1048576 12239
2097152 16516
4194304 16355
```

Линейное чтение с пропусками по 4Мб:

```
# ./diskspeed.sh dev=/dev/sdb testtype=read:4M
512 205
1024 451
2048 912
4096 1816
8192 3217
16384 5859
32768 7921
65536 9677
131072 13008
262144 14916
524288 16175
1048576 16668
2097152 17544
4194304 18123
```

Данные сохраняются в каталоге имя_устройства-метод_чтения, и их можно профильтровать как-нибудь ещё.

PS. С записью что-то мне результаты не очень нравятся: сильно меняются при повторном запуске и намного меньше, чем `dd conv=fdatasync` даже с большими блоками.